# Issue with addClass jQuery and AJAX .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I want when the user clicks a nav link to remove class  from current < li > (this works) and add active class to the clicked one (this does not).

The second thing is that I want to update the .container-fluid div  using AJAX .load() but for some reason does not work. I have a separate html file. I did it before but not using Bootstrap and code worked so I do not know what is the problem now.

Code below

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
/* Act on the event */
var url = this.href;

$('nav li.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');

$(".content").remove();
$(".container-fluid").load(url + '.container-fluid').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

});

HTML - nav

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
     <other bits>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">One </a></li>
          <li><a href="two.html">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
```

And HTML - just the divs responsible for swapping divs on both HTML sites look like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add class to li

change your code to

```
$(this).parent("li").addClass('active');
```

which will add the active class to `li` that has wrapped `a`

Comment: so by (this) I was selecting only <a> wasn't I?

Comment: yes. but you need class on <li> so this changes needs to be done in the code